# blkid not returning the correct UUID/label for drive

Tags: debian, raid, xen, mdadm, uuid

I have 7 drives in my server (running Debian Wheezy as dom0 for a Xen hypervisor): An 80GB system drive, 3 x 2TB drives, a 1TB drive and 2x 500GB drives.

The 2TB drives are all part of an mdadm RAID 5 array (and in my ineffable wisdom I didn't label them), whereas the other drives are all managed by SnapRAID and go by the names '1t', '500g1' and '500g2', respectively.

To simplify the information here, I'll show the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="81db8bc2-6cc1-4272-beab-8c1d667cfa93" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="e3a5165b-0818-bf51-cfdf-f01bce733365" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="500g1" UUID="1aad0eeb-0fc3-47cc-ad4b-54521f2cd6ee" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="e3a5165b-0818-bf51-cfdf-f01bce733365" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="1t" UUID="778dcc42-c74f-433e-b8c0-5228d0134f14" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="500g1" UUID="1aad0eeb-0fc3-47cc-ad4b-54521f2cd6ee" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdg1: LABEL="500g2" UUID="b698ea83-99b2-49c2-90e5-548bff6dcab1" TYPE="ext4"
```

In this case, sdb/c/d1 are the 2TB drives, and should all show `TYPE="linux_raid_member"`, but `sdc1` shows the UUID/label for `sdf1` and `sdd1` shows the UUID/label for `sdb1` (or it could very well be that `sdb1` is showing the UUID/label for `sdd1`).

I'm trying to get the UUIDs for the 2TB drives so that I can pass them on to a VM for management via mdadm. Is there any relatively straightforward way to sort this out?

Comment: What makes you so sure that the UUIDs are wrong? I am more inclined to think you are wrong than the computer :).

Comment: @terdon Mainly because I'm pretty sure two different hard drives can't have identical UUIDs, as in `sdb1` and `sdd1`, and in `sdc1` and `sdf1`.

Comment: Ah, point, yes indeed.